# Finding which file a global variable is stored in

Tags: php, cakephp

I am looking at a PHP file and I see the variable `$myaccounts` used inside of a conditional statement.  The variable isn't defined in this PHP file, so I am assuming this is a global variable.

How would I go about finding in what directory/file this variable is being defined in?

Comment: Please post the relevant code so we have some idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: This is one reason globals are bad. Just search the entire project for 'myaccounts'

Comment: look for include() and required() files in this file.

Comment: Also, if you have an IDE that can perform global searches, just look for `$myaccounts*=` (`*` can be replaced with whatever wildcard character your search function uses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an IDE that can perform global searches, just look for `$myaccounts*=` (`*` can be replaced with whatever wildcard character your search function uses)

Answer (score 0):

If your enviroment has xdebug enabled, you can use it's [tracing functionality](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) to get a list of every single line executed. The configuration you will certainly need is the `xdebug.collect_assignments` set this to `1`. Once you get your trace file, a simple text search for the variable name should reveal every place it's get assigned.

If you can't have xdebug, I would try to have the output of [get_included_files()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) somewhere you see the "$myaccounts" variable and simply search for the text "$myaccounts\s*=" in those, but things like `extract()` can hide assignments.